# Java lady always run when I compile my app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio is very slowly when I compile my Android Application. I noticed that there is always a Java lady pops out automatically then :D (Which never happen when I work on other Android project, very fast)

And when I kill that Java-process, I got this exception in Android Studio's gradle-console:

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

Any idea?
[image]

UPDATE 1:
After deeper research, That Java lady doesn't appear anymore when I put these line into `gradle.properties`. But I still leave this question here for anyone that have more detail description about this and give the best approach if any.

```
android.enableAapt2=false
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

UPDATE 2:
My first update above isn't correctly. It's still appear if my laptop run heavily :|

Comment: What is `Java lady` ? It's called Duke, the Java Mascot. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Duke_(Java_mascot)_waving.svg

Comment: Yah, glad to know it's name now.

Comment: @dit Not mention the name, do you have any idea about my question?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I have never had the problem on OS X, ubuntu or windows environment.